# Shell sorting file according to a pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, awk

Let's say I have two files with the same values in 1st column (different order)

The first one:

```
2 A
6 B
3 C
1 D
4 E
```

And the second one:

```
6 F
3 G
2 H
4 I
1 J
```

I'd like to sort the second file according to the 1st column of the first file. Desirable output:

```
2 H
6 F
3 G
1 J
4 I
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if

- your first column won't have duplicated values
- f1 and f2 have the same values in 1st column.

try this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print a[$1]}' f2 f1
```

Answer (score 0):

Put letters from the second file to the indexes of secondArray according to the numbers:
for e.g.

```
secondArray [6] = F, secondArray [3] = G, secondArray[2] = H
```

and write them, or use the order from the first array to get value by index secondArray

```
result[1] = secondArray[firstArray[1]]
```

where 
    firstArray[1] == 2, firstArray[1] == 6 
and

```
secondArray[firstArray[1]]   == H ,      secondArray[firstArray[2]] ==F
```